# Openlayers3 mousewheelzoom and keyboardzoom doesnt seem to work

Tags: openlayers-3

I want to disable mousewheelzoom and keyboardzoom on openlayers3 map.

I am using it this way with map initialization.

```
interactions: ol.interaction.defaults({MouseWheelZoom:false, KeyboardZoom:false}),
```

However it doesnt seem to work, I can still zoom using mousewheel and with keyboard + and - keys.

Am I doing anything wrong ?

Answer (score 3):

Keys are case sensitive, so `mouseWheelZoom` and `keyboard` see http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.interaction.html#.defaults

Comment: Doesnt work with         interactions: ol.interaction.defaults({mouseWheelZoom:false, keyboardZoom:false}),

Comment: `ol.interaction.defaults({mouseWheelZoom:false, keyboardZoom:false})` should be `ol.interaction.defaults({mouseWheelZoom:false, keyboard:false})`. It works as a charm!!